# New Developer Account?

Tags: force.com, developer

Did anyone try to create a new Developer Account today? I am getting weird issues. When I click on link in email to set new password , a message shows "Your trial is completing the signup process. Please try again in a few moments." And when I try 2nd time I log in. It says "Your login attempt has failed. The username or password may be incorrect, or your location or login time may be restricted. Please contact the administrator at your company for help."

If I click on Forgot password. Its asking me for Mothers Maiden name, which I didnt even set-up in first place.

Comment: I noticed that all the development documents were down today, and my change sets were taking forever, so maybe there was some general slowness with the servers today.

Comment: I've seen similar comments on Twitter about the inability to create Dev orgs.